# Use Int64 (BigInt) for MongoDB's _id

Tags: c#, mongodb

My application utilizes SQL Server and MongoDB. In order to link records / documents from both sides, I'm thinking to use SQL's `BigInt` value (`Int64` in C#) in place of MongoDB's _id. This `BigInt` value is generated from a SQL Server `Identity` column. I thought it's perfect.

However, in this thread [Is it bad to change _id type in MongoDB to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054384/is-it-bad-to-change-id-type-in-mongodb-to-integer)
someone mentioned MongoDB has to check its uniqueness before inserting it. So is it true MongoDB doesn't check uniqueness if `ObjectId.GenerateNewId()` is used otherwise does?

Comment: A point of clarification for interpreting the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054384/) you referenced. ObjectIDs are constructed using a combination of values that have a high probability of uniqueness when generated independently across a cluster of machines, but the `_id` index still ensures uniqueness when inserting new documents. The question was about whether it's a good idea to have *incrementing* numeric IDs. Generating incremental IDs puts a dependency on a central source to find the next number in the sequence (and/or retrying on duplicate key exception).

Comment: In your case, it sounds like you already have assurance that your numeric IDs are unique because you are mirroring data that has been inserted into SQL Server. Using the same primary key in both databases makes sense if the insertions are always flowing from SQL Server to MongoDB (i.e. you don't have to worry about coordinating how the unique IDs are generated).

Comment: So ObjectID is similar to SQL's NEWID(), type of uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Yes, ObjectID to SQL Server's NEWID() is a fair comparison. ObjectIDs are 12-byte unique identifiers; NEWID() generates 16-byte unique identifiers. Both are designed to be independently generated. An [ObjectID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) does have a leading time-based prefix which can be useful for approximate ordering of generated IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb does check uniques of id even if its ObjectId type.

When you create new collection it comes automatically with an unique index on _id field.

> _id Field Index
>
> MongoDB creates the _id index, which is an ascending unique index on
>   the _id field, for all collections when the collection is created. You
>   cannot remove the index on the _id field.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#cases

<s>Exception to this rule are capped collection which does not have this 
index</s>

As Stennie spotted capped collection in MongoDb2.2+ have _id field indexes

Comment: FYI, capped collections created after MongoDB 2.2 also require an indexed unique `_id` field. In particular, the `_id` is [used for replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/#recommendations-and-restrictions).