# Is it a good practice to have a sequential integer id in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I need to create a sequential integer id in mongo for a particular collection. The need arises from a requirement that I need to store these ids in different collection in an array. If I am storing it as Mongo's ObjectID then the array exceeds 16MB document size. So is it possible to create a sequential id starting from 1?

Comment: This talks abut it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054384/is-it-bad-to-change-id-type-in-mongodb-to-integer/14058189#14058189

Comment: however if the array exceeds then you have a serious problem, most likely it wont work with incremental ids either since your array grows even more and then it reaches the limit again

Comment: I agree that reaching the document size limit even with objectID smells like  bad architecture. Is there a way to break up that array to be in more than one collection maybe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it bad to change \_id type in MongoDB to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054384/is-it-bad-to-change-id-type-in-mongodb-to-integer)